# Call sql query synchrously

Tags: mysql, node.js

Currently working on node rest api project where I want to fetch data for a list of data. for example : I have a list of post_id([1,2,3....]) for a particular tag(mobile) and for each post_id I want to retrieve post title and description from mysql database. But calling sql query is synchrounous.

How to control flow for each post id result to combine in one.

my db calling code is here :

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // call body-parser
var addData = require('./dbhandler/addData'); // call database handler to insertdata
var getData = require('./dbhandler/getData');

//route function to get feeds by tags
router.route('/postfeedsbytags/:tag')
// get all new article feeds filtered by tag
.get(function(req,res){
    var success;
    console.log(req.params.tag)
    var json_results = [];
    getData.getPostFeedsByTag(req.params.tag,function(error, results, fields){
        if (!error){
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                getData.getPostFeedsByPostId(results[0]['post_id'],function(error, results, fields){
                    if (!error){
                        success = 1;
                        json_results.push(results[0]);
                        res.json({"success" : success, "datasets" : json_results});
                    } else{
                        success = 0;
                        console.log('Error while performing Query.'+error);
                        res.json({"success" : success});
                    }
                });
            }
            // res.json({"success" : success, "datasets" : results});
        } else{
            success = 0;
            console.log('Error while performing Query.'+error);
            res.json({"success" : success});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the post_id?  If via sql is there any reason you couldn't include post_title and post_description to that array then loop through it?

Comment: I have a table that map tag name with post id

Comment: Show your code. Node.js methods are typically async. If I gather correctly, you want to be able to combine results, right? Sync or Async is not a concern as long as you get your data, right?

Comment: Ok, could you create a select with a join?  For example select t.post_id, t.name as tag_name, p.description as post_description, p.title as post_title from post p left outer join tags t on t.post_id = p.id order by p.published_date;  .  If you create your array on this manner you won't have the problem of synchronous array calls as you can loop through it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the IN operator in the query to get all the posts in a single query and then iterate over it.

If you don't want to use IN operator then use [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) library for flow control. You can use the async.map function from it.